# Overloading operator in class template with more than one template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-classes

Disclaimer: this is a homework assignment, but nothing in the notes or our textbook seems to answer my question, so I'm coming here.

I have a `Queue` template class, and one of the things I need to do is overload the `+` operator to merge two `Queue` objects. I've written it, and I wanted to test it, so I wrote:

```
Queue<int, 25> sum = even + odd;
```

where `even` and `odd` are both `Queue` objects (`even` is `Queue<int, 15>` and `odd` is `Queue<int, 10>`)

This is my declaration of `operator+`:

```
Queue operator+(const Queue& obj) const;
```

And the function implementation header, which is implemented outside the class declaration (if that matters, I don't know):

```
template <typename T, int capacity>  
Queue<T, capacity> Queue<T, capacity>::operator+(const Queue& obj) const {
    Queue<T, 25> result; // not the literal 25, but effectively 25 just for demonstration  
    // some logic  
    return result;
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Queue<int, 15>' and 'Queue<int, 10>')
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Queue<int, 10>' to 'const Queue<int, 15>&'
```

I tried writing an `add(const Queue& obj)` method, but that spat out even more errors, because neither class could convert to `Queue<int, 25>`.

I've also tried changing which `Queue`'s in the implementation have a template argument added to them, but that also just gave more errors.

Answer (score 3):

Your `operator+` only allows the same `Queue` type to be passed to it, and returned from it.  But `Queue<int, 15>`, `Queue<int, 10>`, and `Queue<int, 25>` are all different and distinct types.  You need to use a separate set of template parameters on the operator's input parameter and return type, eg:

```
template <typename T, int capacity>  
class Queue
{
...
    template <int Other_capacity>
    Queue<T, capacity + Other_capacity> operator+(const Queue<T, Other_capacity>& obj) const;
...
};
```

```
template <typename T, int capacity>
template <int Other_capacity>
Queue<T, capacity + Other_capacity> Queue<T, capacity>::operator+(const Queue<T, Other_capacity>& obj) const {  
    Queue<T, capacity + Other_capacity> result;
    // some logic  
    return result;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/1hMLRx)

Comment: I actually didn't know you could have multiple templates in a header, thanks for that! That implementation looks so sensible after reading it, and it let my program compile (when I commented out all the other logic for the operator lol). Thank you!